# How to update dataframe value

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a project where for each row in a table I need to iterate through rows from another table and update values in both. The changes need to stick for the next iteration. What is the best way to do that?

```
for invoice_line in invoices.itertuples():
    qty = invoice_line.SHIP_QTY
    for receipt_line in receipts[receipts.SKU == invoice_line.SKU].itertuples():
        if qty > receipt_line.REC_QTY:
            receipts.set_value(receipt_line.index,'REC_QTY',0)
            qty = qty - receipt_line.REC_QTY
        else:
            receipts.set_value(receipt_line.index,'REC_QTY', receipt_line.REC_QTY - qty)
            qty = 0
        recd = receipt_line.REC_DATE
        if qty < 1:break
    invoices.set_value(invoice_line.index,'REC_DATE',recd)
```

set_value does not seem to work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

for row in df.itertuples():
    df.set_value(row.index,'test',row.D)

print df.head()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you want is a capitalized `Index`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

for row in df.itertuples():
    df.set_value(row.Index,'test',row.D)

print df.head()
```

Comment: this is definitely helpful! wish i had enough reputation to upvote you.

Comment: If this answers your question you can click the green checkbox under the vote arrows. If not hold out for a better answer =).

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure if this is what you want, but I think you're trying to loop thru a list and update the value of a cell in a dataframe. The syntax for that is:

```
for ix in df.index:
    df.loc[ix, 'Test'] = 'My New Value'
```

where ix is the row position and 'Test' is the column name that you want to update. If you need to add more logic, you could try somthing like:

```
for ix in df.index:
    row = df.loc[ix]
    if row.myVariable < 100:
         df.loc[ix, 'SomeColumn'] = 'Less than ahundred'
    else:
         df.loc[ix, 'SomeColumn'] = 'ahundred or more'
```